# Why can't spark references be found?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There are several base classes and Imps:

```
abstract class BaseClass(@transient spark: SparkSession)

abstract class BaseClass2(@transient val spark: SparkSession)

abstract class BaseClass3(@transient private val spark: SparkSession)

class Imp(spark: SparkSession) extends BaseClass(spark) {
   import spark.implicites._
}

class Imp2(spark: SparkSession) extends BaseClass2(spark) {
  import spark.implicits._
}

class Imp3(spark: SparkSession) extends BaseClass3(spark) {
  import spark.implicits._
}
```

Imp and Imp3 are fine, but Imp2 raises an error:

**Can not resolve symbol spark**

Why can't it find it?

jetbrain intellij CE (gradle scala plugin)

Comment: Excluding discarded annotations and typos (`implicites`) this compiles just fine. Could you include build definition.